# How to renew my existing AWS IAM SSL certificate on ELB without replacing it with the new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-iam

I have an IAM SSL certificate attached to an ELB. It is about to expire in a day or two. I know I can create a new certificate and upload it to use this but this will affect my clients who are already using my application.They would be requiring to install the new certificate which they aren't ready to do. Is there any way where i can renew this IAM certificate without replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by IAM SSL certificate.  In AWS you can import external certificates, or generate domain-validated certificates using the AWS Certificate Manager.

Assuming ACM is where your cert lives, you can simply update the cert attached to the ELB and there should be no impact to your end users - there should be nothing for the clients to install, they will simply use the new one presented by the ELB.

Comment: [IAM Server Certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html) was the way you stored SSL certs and keys for loading into ELB Classic and CloudFront before ACM was introduced.  It's still available but not as polished or convenient as ACM.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for the certificate authority that provided you with the certificate.

IAM only provides you with secure storage of server certificates and deployment to balancers and/or CloudFront -- IAM doesn't issue certs.

Depending on exactly how the clients are dependent on the certificate, you may have a problem on your hands.  If it is just pinned, then you can obtain a new cert from your CA with the same public key... but if they are dependent on that specific certificate, there is no resolution for this.  Certificates are immutable.  They cannot be modified under any circumstances.  Any time a certificate is said to have been "renewed," it is in fact being *replaced* by a new certificate. Typically the new cert will be one with the same subject and extensions, but it is necessarily an entirely different certificate.